# issue uploading image on symfony

Tags: php, image, symfony, image-uploading

```
   /**
    * Upload the image while creating/updating records
    * @param File Object $file
    */
    public function setImageAttribute($file)
    {
        // Only if a file is selected
        if ($file) {
            File::exists(public_path() . '/uploads/') || File::makeDirectory(public_path() . '/uploads/');
            File::exists(public_path() . '/' . $this->images_path) || File::makeDirectory(public_path() . '/' . $this->images_path);
            File::exists(public_path() . '/' . $this->thumbs_path) || File::makeDirectory(public_path() . '/' . $this->thumbs_path);
            $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $image = Image::make($file->getRealPath());
            if (isset($this->attributes['image'])) {
                // Delete old image
                $old_image = $this->getImageAttribute();
                File::exists($old_image) && File::delete($old_image);
            }
            if (isset($this->attributes['thumb'])) {
                // Delete old thumbnail
                $old_thumb = $this->getThumbAttribute();
                File::exists($old_thumb) && File::delete($old_thumb);
            }
            $image->save($this->images_path . $file_name)
                  ->fit(640, 180)
                  ->save($this->thumbs_path . $file_name);
            $this->attributes['image'] = $file_name;
        }
    }
```

**and this is my error msg**

```
production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object' in C:\Doptor\app\components\posts\models\Post.php:79
```

line 79 is here

```
$file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$image = Image::make($file->getRealPath());
```

Comment: Obviously `$file` doesn't evaluate to `false` *but* it's not an object, i.e. it's a string... So back to debugging to find out what type `$file` has, I'd say

Comment: use typehint - `public function setImageAttribute(UploadedFile $file)`

Answer (score 0):

Check out this entry in the cookbook since I think you will get this easier uploading your [image directly with Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html).

Secondly, you can also probe that your $file is the right object by checking this:

```
if ($file instanceof UploadedFile) {
  // do stuff
} else {
 exit("file is not the right object, so getClientOriginalName will not work");
}
```